# Microsoft Visual Studio 2017 Not Opening. [Error:800703f1]

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, activitylog

Today i triend to remove software in name `DriverAgentPlus`
and for that I should download another software that called `CleanMyPc`.
After i finish to use in this software i restarted my Computer with Visual Studio Open.. 
(I believe that there connection between these things.)
Now after my computer restarted Visual Studio not opening me and showing me:
 
"Unknown Error.
you can get more information by examining the file activitylog.xml"

and here the file:
[activitylog.xml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P9ZUY.png)

Comment: Registry cleaner utilities are very, very dangerous.  Maybe you can rescue the machine by restoring a restore-point or re-installing VS2017.

Comment: @HansPassant yeah i realize now that i cleaned my Registry with `CleanMyPc` and i didn't know what this thing.. i'm dumb :\
and where i can see all my restore points?

Comment: @HansPassant not cleaning.. hmm the software told me that it fixing